# DataStax OpsCenter - can't connect with agents

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter, database, nosql

I've installed DataStax OpsCenter (Apache Cassandra) and in OpsCenter, there is an error: "0 of 1 agents connected". When I click "fix", enter credentials and try to install nodes, i get error:

> Unable to SSH to some of the hosts
>
> Unable to SSH to 127.0.0.1:
> global name 'get_output' is not defined

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: From the DataStax support forum: [0 of 1 agents connected : Unable to connect to Node](http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/0-of-1-agents-connected-unable-to-connect-to-node). This probably belongs on another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Are you running opscenter on Windows?

Comment: Yes, Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with instruction from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418995/datastax-opscenter-agent-doesnt-connect-unable-to-locate-cassandra-yaml-confi.)

The reason is OpsCenter could not find correct cassandra config file (cassandra.yaml).

In my case I installed cassandra to "D:\DataStax" instead of default location "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community". Add `conf_location` to `opscenter\conf\clusters\local.conf` solved my problem.

This is my final setting:

```
conf_location = [DataStax Install Dir]\apache-cassandra\conf\cassandra.yaml
```

Comment: That was probably the issue - when I reinstalled OpsCenter into default directory, everything worked fine :) Thanks